# Facebook php SDK: On entering IP in App Domains, shows error as 'Invalid Domain'

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I am want to do login and register using Facebook-PHP-SDK in to my project. In the App Domains Field, I entered my IP as `192.168.10.10` then it showed error as

```
App Domains: 192.168.10.10 is not a valid domain.
```

What I want is, when I click on Login Using Facebook Icon, it should login and get my data from Facebook database and insert it into my custom database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer, I did following things:

```
1) APP Domainds: 'this is left blank'

2) Site URL: http://192.168.1.10/

3) Canvas URL: http://192.168.1.10/

4) Secure Canvas URL: https://192.168.1.10/
```

Answer (score 0):

*USUALLY* third party authentication (OpenAuth/Facebook/Twitter) does not work with internal IP addresses. You should try with the FQDN of your website (eg. www.mywebsite.com)

edit:
try this:
[edit your hosts file](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) and at the last line add this:

```
192.168.10.10 www.mysite.com
```

Use "www.mysite.com" instead of 192.168.10.10 in Facebook-PHP-SDK. It might also help to change the base_url to "http://www.mysite.com/" in CI's config.php

Comment: well, I dont have it, so what should I do?